# order while using pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

How can I keep the initial order of my pandas while I using pivot_table ?

I use pandas version '1.2.5' (so I can't use the pivot_table "order" argument)

For instance

```
data =pd.DataFrame(data={
'x_values':[13.4, 13.08, 12.73],
'y_values': [1.54, 1.47, 1.46],
'experiment':['e', 'e', 'e']})
```

gives

```
   x_values  y_values experiment
0     13.40      1.54          e
1     13.08      1.47          e
2     12.73      1.46          e
```

and if I use pivot_table the order of my initial pandas is not kept

```
data =  pd.pivot_table(data, index='x_values', columns='experiment', values='y_values')
```

gives

```
experiment     e
x_values        
12.73       1.46
13.08       1.47
13.40       1.54
```

In the real code I don't know the order of x_values.

I just want to keep the order as it is in my pandas ...

Answer (score 1):

Due to nature of `pivot` it always sort the index. You might want to pivot with the original index.

```
data.reset_index().pivot_table(index=['index','x_values'], values='y_values', columns='experiment')
```

You can also use `set_index().unstack()`:

```
data.set_index(['x_values', 'experiment'], append=True)['y_values'].unstack('experiment')
```

Output:

```
experiment     e
  x_values      
0 13.40     1.54
1 13.08     1.47
2 12.73     1.46
```

Comment: thanks 

data.set_index(...) gives  "None of ['x_values', 'experiment'] are in the columns" ...

Comment: You should double check the column names. The two approaches are essentially the same. I checked on the sample data.

Comment: you were right ...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to upgrade the pandas version (min 1.3.0) and use 'sort' argument

```
data =  pd.pivot_table(data, index='x_values', columns='experiment', values='y_values')
```